# Why opencv not able to access last frames of video

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to do a very basic thing with OpenCV in Python: get frames of the videofile, to be able later on analyze them with skimage and save them as pictures.
I have 10s video to test, and I am getting single frame of the video with

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path) 
length_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_n = 305
cap.set(1,frame_n)
ret, frame = cap.read()
t = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
cv2.imshow('frame '+str(frame_n+1), frame)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.imwrite(path.split(".")[0]+'_frame_'+str(frame_n+1)+'.jpg', frame)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is, that total amount of frames `length_frames=340`, meanwhile I am able to get only from from 0 to 305 (so I am unable to access last second of the video). If I pass frame_n>305, I get an error message

```
6 ret, frame = cap.read()
7 t = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
----> 8 cv2.imshow('frame '+str(frame_n+1), frame)
9 cv2.waitKey()
10 cv2.imwrite(path.split(".")[0]+'_frame_'+str(frame_n+1)+'.jpg', frame)
error: C:\bld\opencv_1496444098483\work\opencv-3.2.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

fps also a bit weird - shows 33 frames/s, and I was expecting something like 24 or 30. Video was recorded with Astra Image Webcam Video Grabber, with simple webcamera, which is noname, so I don't have idea what is the real fps. According to Astra Video Grabber itself, which shows amount of recorded frames in real-time, along with recorded time, fps is just 15 frames/s. But eventually length of video is few seconds longer, then shows Astra Video Grubber. So I am wondering, could it be the problem of camera itself, and how it was recorded? Although if I play video, I can play it completely, including last second.

I tried it with several videos, and with all of them it is the same: opencv counts more frames, than I can access.

**UPD**: Thanks to @AlexanderReynolds comment, turned out that there is a library `sci-kit video`, with which importing the video and getting the frames is extremely easy:

```
videodata = skvideo.io.vread(file)
frame_i = videodata[i]  # getting i frame, which can be directly analyzed with skimage
frame_n = len(videodata) # total number of the frames in the video
```

And number of the frames, calculated with skivideo, is the expected one.

Comment: If you're going to be using `skimage`, why not skip OpenCV and just use [`skvideo`](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html) in the first place? The capability is really good. OpenCV reads the FPS straight from the metadata, but maybe it's variable? It looks like you're using Windows, try probing the metadata directly through the shell with [`System.Video.FrameRate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760066(v=vs.85).aspx).